# PlayerCenteredScores in LeaderBoards

Tags: android, libgdx, leaderboards, google-play-services

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadPlayerCenteredScores(mGoogleApiClient,leaderboardId, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 5).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult>()
{
    public void onResult(Leaderboards.LoadScoresResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       int size = arg0.getScores().getCount();
        Log.e("ACHGOD", "SIZE="+Integer.toString(size));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            LeaderboardScore lbs = arg0.getScores().get(i);
            // String name = lbs.getScoreHolderDisplayName();
            String score = lbs.getDisplayScore();
            Log.e("ACHGOD", "SCORE="+score);
            //Uri urlimage = lbs.getScoreHolderHiResImageUri();
        }
        // arg0.getScores().close();
        arg0.getScores().release();
    }
});
```

I am getting the integer score value here. But, I could not find any proper documentation regarding the score value, which I get.

Is it the high score? Or, is it the last submitted score? I am looking to get the highest score made by the currently logged-in user from the leaderboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScoreBuffer) isn't clear about the ordering of the scores. When the documentation doesn't guarantee any kind of order, guarantee it yourself.

I suggest you simply iterate through the list, keeping track of the largest (for O(N) time).